# Can I hide the horizontal overflow in s:List component in flex?

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, horizontal-scrolling

wondering if there's any way to make it so that a list I have will not scroll to show the horizontal end of the items. Very few items go long enough to require it and the horizontal scrollbar is distracting.

I don't see any property to control that, though, so not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List component includes a Scroller skin part that handles scrolling.  There are a few ways to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar, but the easiest is probably to set the horizontalScrollPolicy on the scroller in a creation complete event handler:

```
private function onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void {
    myList.scroller.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: FYI - In the Hero release verticalScrollPolicy/horizontalScrollPolicy styles are now exposed in MXML on the spark List.

Comment: @StevenShongrunden: works but the item width is still oversized :-(
my item -> label is not truncut